# Motorola MC9190 CE: Cannot find server or DNS error

Tags: windows

We are using Motorola MC9190 CE device. When I am trying to open google.com or any other website in IE of the device, I am getting the below error message

### The page you are looking for is currently unavailable. The web site might be experiencing technical difficulties, or you may need to adjust your browser settings.

Cannot find server or DNS error
Internet Explorer.

I am connecting my device to my computer to access the internet. I was to able to browse the internet. All of sudden I am getting the above error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

### Steps:

- Check your synchronize settings on your PC and PDA.
- Also try checking the network environment of the PDA.(Proxy server)